# Class type transformation?

Tags: groovy

Why does

```
var = java.util.List
println var
```

results in following output: `interface java.util.List`?

I would expect `java.util.List` to be printed instead. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're seeing is the output of `Class.toString()`. If you need just the name, you can retrieve it using `getName()`

```
println var.getName()
```

Or, groovier:

```
println var.name
```

Both of which print `java.util.List`. `getName()` returns the fully-qualified name of the type, and would omit the class type added by the `toString()` method.